# Adding active User_id to a title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to add a User_id to a created movie title so that I can only show the movie titles that the user created in his profile.

I have done a few things but when I create a new title (as a logged in user) and then check in the rails console to see if that movie has a User_id it says "nil". So it would seem I've done something wrong or forgot to do something.

This is my schema, I already had a Movie model so I used `rails g migration addUserIdToMovies user_id:integer` to add the User_id to the Movies model

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141016152516) do

  create_table "movies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

I've added the has_many and belongs_to to the User and Movie model

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :movies
```

Movie model

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :users
```

The question is, why am I not getting a User_id in my movie collumn `User_id` when I post a new movie as a logged in user?

Comment: Is your login using sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sessions for tracking the user that is currently logged in, you can create a simple method in your application controller like this:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  return @current_user
end
```

and call for it in the create action of your Movie controller

```
def create
    @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])
    @user = current_user
    user_id = @user[:id]
    @movie[:user_id] = user_id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @move.save
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @movie, status: :created, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is this a better method then the join table method shown here http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many ?

Comment: That makes sence, could you point out how I would only show the movies the user made on his profile page? Right now I'm using `@movies = Movie.all` in the User controller with this code in my view `- @movies.each do |movie|
  = movie.title`

Comment: Found it! `@movies = @user.movies` this gets all the movies posted by the user!